# python bug - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc0EN.png)I am trying to run my python server and I got this error

```
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/authors_api/settings/local.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import * #noqa
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/authors_api/settings/base.py", line 85, in <module>
    DATABASES = {"default": env.db("DATABASE_URL")}
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 295, in db_url
    self.get_value(var, default=default),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/solnsnday/Documents/Workspace/authors-haven/src/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 391, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable
(venv) solnsnday@Solomons-MBP src %
```

This is my local.py[setting.py]

```
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path


import environ

env = environ.Env()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


APP_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "core_apps"


DEBUG = env.bool("DJANGO_DEBUG", False)
# Application definition


DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "rest_framework",
    "django_filters", 
    "django_countries", 
    "phonenumbers",
    "phonenumber_field",
    "drf_yasg",
    "corsheaders",
]

LOCAL_APPS = ["core_apps.profiles", "core_apps.common", "core_apps.users",]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware", 
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "authors_api.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "authors_api.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     "default": {
#         "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
#         "NAME": "mydatabase",
#     }
# }
DATABASES = {"default": env.db("DATABASE_URL")}
```

And my postgres envs varaible is here

```
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_POST=5432
POSTGRES_DB=authors-live
POSTGRES_USER=solomonsunday
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Pass123456
DATABASE_URL=postgres://solomonsunday:Pass123456@postgres:5432/authors-live[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW2pJ.png)
```

It looks like the local.py[setting.py] cannot access the DATABASE_URL variable from the .envs/.local/postgress.

Not sure what is cuaseing this. I have tried everything possible to make this work. I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing that would read `.envs/.local/postgress` that I can see. `Env.read_envfile()` would read one...